# HHVM settings for Kohana

Tags: php, kohana, hhvm

I have an application running with Kohana 3.1, NGINX with PHP-FPM. I am trying to replace PHP-FPM with HHVM to handle more number of requests.

the code is

```
public function action_test(){
    echo 'Hi';
}
```

With 100 requests per second the CPU goes to 200% and load average to 15!

If I replace Kohana with static php file. The same server can handle 200 requests with load average just 3.

With Kohana HHVM behaves worse than PHP-FPM. Am I doing something wrong with the configuration?

```
Server {
 Port = 9000
  Type = fastcgi
  SourceRoot = /mypath/to/php/repo
  DefaultDocument = index.php
  ThreadCount = 20
}

Eval {
  Jit = true
  EnableObjDestructCall = true
}
Log {
  Level = Warning
  UseLogFile = true
  File = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
  InjectedStackTrace = true
  NativeStackTrace = true
  NoSilencer = on
  Header = on
  Access {
    * {
      File = /var/log/hhvm/access.log
      Format = %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b
    }
  }
}

VirtualHost {
  * {
    Pattern = .*
    RewriteRules {
      dirindex {
        pattern = ^/(.*)/$
        to = $1/index.php
        qsa = true
      }
    }
  }
}
StaticFile {
  FilesMatch {
    * {
      pattern = .*\.(dll|exe)
      headers {
        * = Content-Disposition: attachment
      }
    }
  }
  Extensions {
    css = text/css
    gif = image/gif
    html = text/html
    jpe = image/jpeg
    jpeg = image/jpeg
    jpg = image/jpeg
    png = image/png
    tif = image/tiff
    tiff = image/tiff
    txt = text/plain
  }
}
ResourceLimit {
    CoreFileSize = 0          # in bytes
    MaxSocket = 50000         # must be not 0, otherwise HHVM will not start
    SocketDefaultTimeout = 5  # in seconds
    MaxRSS = 0
    MaxRSSPollingCycle = 0    # in seconds, how often to check max memory
    DropCacheCycle = 0        # in seconds, how often to drop disk cache
}
```

Comment: Can the issue be caused by your disk? We're running a very heavy platform with hundreds/thousands of often concurrent users, with tens/hundreds of database calls for each request (DB server is on the same server), and we don't reach the load level of your static script. Both Nginx and HHVM log access logs (and probably error logs if there are any in your code). A large amount of logging could increase i/o wait time.

Comment: Can you run `dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=64k count=16k conv=fdatasync` and paste the result?

Comment: Here is the result
`16384+0 records in`
`16384+0 records out`
`1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 45.4716 s, 23.6 MB/s`
I am monitoring iostat extended but that does not show anything alarming

Comment: I think the number of threads are culprit. I am on ec2 m3.large which has 2 vCPU. When I reduced the number of threads to 20 it was able to handle 100 requests under 1 load average. But that breaks at 200 requests/second.

Comment: Your disk speed appears to be quite slow. The number of CPUs certainly plays an important factor as well. 2 cpu cores should find it hard to execute simultaneous 20 threads. Rule of thumb would be 2-4 threads. If the code doesn't have much I/O (to justify interrupts), I assume threads should start blocking each other